# How do I search something in a nested dictionary and modify the nested dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def remove_unknown_movies(user_ratings: UserRatingDict, 
                          movies: MovieDict) -> None:
    """Modify the user_ratings dictionary so that only movie ids that are in the
    movies dictionary is remaining. Remove any users in user_ratings that have
    no movies rated.

    >>> small_ratings = {1001: {68735: 5.0, 302156: 3.5, 10: 4.5}, 1002: {11: 3.0}}
    >>> remove_unknown_movies(small_ratings, MOVIE_DICT_SMALL)
    >>> len(small_ratings)
    1
    >>> small_ratings[1001]
    {68735: 5.0, 302156: 3.5}
    >>> 1002 in small_ratings
    False
    """
```

Comment: How do i go about this question. Could somone help me? Thank you

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Comment: for v in user_ratings:
        for i in v:
            i.isdigit()
            if i not in movies:
                return user_ratings[i].remove(i)

Comment: I have tried thi code but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: [Edit] the question to give a [mcve]. I'd recommend taking the [tour] and learning [ask].

Answer (score 0):

As there is a lot of information missing from your example. If you update your post with a n reproducible example then I will edit my answer.

This will check for the keys in each dictionary/nested dictionary, if it is found it will not delete it, but if it is it will delete current key and the function will return and replace the MOVIE_DICT_SMALL dictionary.

```
from recommender_constants import MovieDict,UserRatingDict,USER_RATING_DICT_SMALL,MOVIE_DICT_SMALL
import copy
small_ratings = {1001: {68735: 5.0, 302156: None, 10: 4.5}, 1002: {11: 3.0}}


def remove_unknown_movies(user_ratings: UserRatingDict, movies: MovieDict) -> None:
    """Modify the user_ratings dictionary so that only movie ids that are in the
    movies dictionary is remaining. Remove any users in user_ratings that have
    no movies rated."""
    copy_user_ratings = copy.deepcopy(user_ratings)
    for k,v in copy_user_ratings.items():        
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for item,value in v.items():
                #check if item is in movies keys
                if item not in movies.keys():
                    print("Not found",item)
                    #verify if nested dictionary contains only one item on deletion, if it does delete key as dictionary is empty
                    if len(copy_user_ratings[k]) == 1:
                        del user_ratings[k][item]
                        del user_ratings[k]
                    else:
                        #delete otherwise key in values
                        del user_ratings[k][item]
                else:
                    print("Found",item)
                    # deletes key if value is None or empty string
                    if value == None or value == "":
                        del user_ratings[k][item]
        else:
            pass

remove_unknown_movies(small_ratings,MOVIE_DICT_SMALL)
print(small_ratings)
```

Comment: What i want to do is if there is a key for example, movie_id like 68735 in the nested dictionary of user_ratings and it is not there in the dictionary of movies I want to remove that key

Comment: Yes despite me not giving enough information you were able to figure it out. Its not exactly what i wanted but it does 80% of the job. Thanks a lot Drees appreciate it

Comment: It just seems like I am having trouble with 'copy.deepcopy(user_ratings)' area python shell tells me there is a NameError for 'copy'

Comment: @KabirSingh Did you import copy?

Comment: @KabirSingh I added a statement to check if there is an empty dictionary value and will delete it if found

Comment: I have upvoted but I am new so not sure it counts. It isnt solved yet though as I am receiving this: File "/Users/Admin/Desktop/a3_files/recommender_functions.py", line 134, in <module>
    if item not in movies[k].keys().int():
builtins.KeyError: 1001

Comment: @KabirSingh [Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197640/help-questionnested-dictionary) Click on link it will take you to chat room

Comment: Ok, did you copy and paste my answer or edit, if you have email I can email you to

Comment: I copied and pasted it into my Wing101. yes my email is kskabir8@gmail.com. Thank you once again

Comment: @KabirSingh ok, I’ve emailed you.